# How to launch many instances of the Sun JavaME Platform SDK 3.0 emulator?

Tags: netbeans, java-me, emulation, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

I want to launch two instances of the emulator , how to achieve that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*User Guide* should have instructions on how to do that.

Two instances support is definitely there, it was introduced long time ago (when emulator was called WTK). Iirc it was done to simulate [JSR 120 WMA](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=120) features like sending SMS from one device to another